# RTK Query custom query function loading

Tags: reactjs, redux-toolkit

How do I correctly return a loading state in a queryFn?

Below is not actually rendering a spinner for some reason. Is the implementation correct?

```
    getUserSurveys: builder.query({
      async queryFn(surveysIds, _queryApi, _extraOptions, fetchWithBQ) {
        const results = await Promise.all(
          surveysIds.map((id) => fetchWithBQ(`/getSurvey?id=${id}`))
        );

        const merged = [].concat(...results.map((r) => r.data));
        const errors = [].concat(
          ...results
            .filter((result) => result.error != null)
            .map((result) => result.error)
        );

        const isLoading = results.some((result) => result.status === 'pending');

        if (isLoading) return { isLoading };

        if (errors.length > 0) return { error: errors };

        return { data: merged };
      },
    }),
```

I'm using it like this:

```
  const { data: userSurveys, isLoading: isUserSurveysLoading } =
    useGetUserSurveysQuery(linkedSurveysIds);
```

Comment: Do you just need to know when a query is actively fetching data?

Comment: Correct. I just want to render a spinner when data are first fetching. Not on every subsequent refetch of the data.

Comment: I actually changed `some` to `every` and changed `pending` to `loading` and it seems to be working now. But I don't understand why. Could you please explain?

Comment: IIRC "loading" is used on the initial request when there's nothing in the cache, otherwise all other requests will be "pending" since there's cached response data. Switching from `.some` to `.every` means that *all* requests need to have the same status. With `.some` if any one array element meets the predicate then the rest of the array is ignored, i.e. *some* request is "pending" or "loading". `.some` seems like it *should* be the correct array method to use though. This logic ***is*** running *after* all the Promises have resolved though since they are `await`ed.

Comment: Thank you! I agree `.some` should be the correct way. That's why I was surprised that it's working now. It's the exact behavior I want. It's now rendering a loading spinner then showing the merged data. It shouldn't work though. What is the implication of the logic running after the `await`? Do you know how native queries in RTK query handle the `isLoading` state?

Comment: I've not ever queued multiple requests per query, but my guess is that the `isLoading` you are computing in the `queryFn` has nothing to do with any of the query status returned from the `useGetUserSurveysQuery` hook. I think you should be able to just await the requests to all resolve and simply return the merged data (or error), and the query hook computes the derived `isLoading` and `isFetching` statuses. `queryFn` is returning data to be cached in the store.

Comment: Okay when removing my custom isLoading logic, the spinner is not rendering (meaning the isLoading boolean is not correct). Adding the `.every` line makes it work again. In the rtk query documentation they don't mentioned how to handle this case.

Comment: This is the only thing I see dealing with making multiple requests per query: https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/customizing-queries#performing-multiple-requests-with-a-single-query

Comment: Yes thank you Drew I check out that one. I ended up solving this by modifying the firebase cloud function to include an api endpoint for fetching multiple surveys and merging the data in the backend. Then I'm using RTK query to do a post request and send the ids in the body. This solved the problem. Thank you for your help. Appreciate that!

Comment: It makes more sense to do that in the first place, sending one request for all the data you need versus individual requests. Nice.

Answer (score 0):

For those reading this in the future, I wasn't able to solve this exact problem. However, because I'm using Firebase cloud functions as a proxy to fetch data from the 3rd party API, I created a new endpoint (cloud function) that contains the custom logic for fetching multiple items using axios and merging the data into a single array.

So I solved the problem in the backend not in RTK Query.

Here is my function:

```
exports.getUserSurveys = functions
  .region('somewhere')
  .https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
    cors(req, res, async () => {
      try {
        const { ids } = req.body;
        const surveyData = await Promise.all(
          ids.map(async (id) => {
            const { data } = await customAPI.get(`/surveys/${id}`);
            return data.result;
          })
        );
        const combinedSurveyData = [].concat(...surveyData); // merge survey data into a single array
        res.send(combinedSurveyData);
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    });
  });
```

Now the `ids` are sent as an array in the request body.

Then in my api slice:

```
 getUserSurveys: builder.query({
      query: (ids) => ({
        url: '/getUserSurveys',
        method: 'POST',
        body: { ids },
      }),
    }),
```